# при создании директории появляется папка .idea

Tags: pycharm

В директории вместе с проектом пайчарм проектом появляется новая папка .idea и так всегда. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы она не появлялась?

Comment: Можно! Не запускайте продукты IDEA. В папке .idea лежат настройки проекта для вашей IDE, индексированный код для поиска, взаимосвязи, зависимости и т.д.

Comment: с точки начинаются скрытые файлы, можете просто настроить файловый менеджер чтобы он не отображал такие файл (даже если они есть)

Comment: @DaniilLoban это в линуксе они скрытые. А в винде самые обычные.

Comment: Ну прими это как данность это как проекты в Visual Studio .vcxproj
Конфигурация самого проекта в IDE. Это нормально ну конечно всегда для тру девов есть блокнот++))

Comment: @Эникейщик ну да, давно я не сидел на винде, но там тоже есть скрытые файлы и можно это организовать при желании, думаю IDE не обидится и отыщет)